# Complete the assembly program

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am given part of a program written in LC3 and told to add in the missing parts. Fortunately, I was able to find the answer online, but that doesn't help me understand why the answer is the way it is or how I know to write a specific instruction. Here is the code (with the answers), and I will mark the lines that we were to add in with the letters (a) - (e). The program determines whether a character string is a palindrome or not.

```
      .ORIG x3000
      LEA R0, PTR
      ADD R1, R0, #0
AGAIN LDR R2, R1, #0
      BRz CONT
      ADD R1, R1, #1
      BRnzp AGAIN
CONT  ADD R1, R1, #-1 --> (a)
LOOP  LDR R3, R0, #0
      LDR R4, R1, #0 -->(b)
      NOT R4, R4
      ADD R4, R4, #1
      ADD R3, R3, R4
      BRnp NO
      ADD R0, R0, #1 --> (c)
      ADD R1, R1, #-1 --> (d)
      NOT R2, R0
      ADD R2, R2, #1
      ADD R2, R1, R2
      BRnz YES
      BR LOOP --> (e)
YES   AND R5, R5, #0
      ADD   R5, R5, #1
      BRnzp DONE
NO    AND R5, R5, #0
DONE  HALT
PTR   .FILL X4000
.END
```

The only one here that I thought was obvious was (e) since there was no BR LOOP to take you back up to the top of the loop. Can anyone help explain why these commands work and how to go about thinking to come up with them? For instance, how am I supposed to know to add in "LDR R4, R1, #0" in for part (b)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before you can understand each line in detail, you need to understand what the program is trying to accomplish. We can see this is a routine that checks to make sure the values stored after *PTR* are equal. If the values meet this requirement then this routine sets *R5* to 1, else it sets *R5* to 0.

**Line (a):** we need this line because the first loop is checking every memory location after *PTR* until it finds an empty memory block (searches for null), the code `ADD R1, R1, #-1` takes us from that null memory to the last nonzero memory location.

**Line (b):** since our sub-routine needs to compare two different memory locations we need to load the value originally stored in *R1*. the reason we load that value into *R4* is because the code after that line is inverting the *R4* register.

**Line (c) and Line (d):** we have to include these lines to move to the next blocks in memory for comparison. In the example below I've included a few more values after PTR:

```
PTR    .FILL x4000    ; Stored at x3019
       .FILL x400F    ; Stored at x301A
       .FILL x40FF    ; Stored at x301B
       .FILL x4000    ; Stored at x301C
```

In the first check **R0 = x3019**, and **R1 = x301C**. Since the value stored at x3019 equals the value stored at x301C we loop again.

In the second check **R0 = x301A**, and **R1 = x301B**. Since the values stored in x301A and x301B don't equal one another, our routine exits and sets *R5* = 0.

Comment: I hope this helps, this sub-routine was a bit convoluted. If you have specific questions, I'll do my best to help answer them.

Comment: I guess my question is, how can you tell its checking memory locations and searching for null? I see "ADD R1, R1, #1" and I think to myself "Adding 1 to the value stored in R1, and storing it into R1." How did you know that it was checking memory locations? I struggle with interpreting LC-3 code really bad.

Comment: no problem, asm isn't as intuitive as other high level languages. We  can tell that's what the program is looking for in the first loop because of the "BRz CONT". it's saying branch if zero, but that only gives us the memory location of the empty block of memory, so the "ADD R1, R1, #-1" is like stepping back to the last "filled" memory location.

Comment: It's like driving down a street with rows of homes, and your friend calls to tell you his home is the last one on the street. So the LC3 is cruising down this street until it finds an empty lot, then says it must have been that last house I passed and reverses one block of memory.